# Running two browser instances in parallel for same list of websites in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

I wrote javascript code for a web crawler that scraps data from a list of websites (in csv file) in a single browser instance (code below). Now I want to modify the code for the scenario in which every single website in the list runs parallel at the same time in two browser instances. For example, a website [www.a.com](http://www.a.com) in the list should run in parallel at the same time on two browser instances and the same goes for the rest of the websites. If anyone can help me, please. I would be very thankful.

(async () => {

```
require("dotenv").config();
if (!process.env.PROXY_SPKI_FINGERPRINT) {
    throw new Error("PROXY_SPKI_FINGERPRINT is not defined in environment.");
}

const fs = require("fs");
const fsPromises = fs.promises;
const pptr = require("puppeteer");

const browser = await pptr.launch({
    args: [
        "--proxy-server=https://127.0.0.1:8000",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=" + process.env.PROXY_SPKI_FINGERPRINT,
        "--disable-web-security",
    ],
    // headless: false,
});

const sites = (await fsPromises.readFile(process.argv[2])) // sites list in csv file
    .toString()
    .split("\n")
    .map(line => line.split(",")[1])
    .filter(s => s);

for (let i in sites) {
    const site = sites[i];
    console.log(`[${i}] ${site}`);
    try {
        await fsPromises.appendFile("data.txt", JSON.stringify(await crawl(browser, site)) + "\n");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

await browser.close();

async function crawl(browser, site) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        const grepResult = [];

        page.on("request", async request => {
            request.continue();
        })

        page.on("response", async response => {
            try {
                if (response.request().resourceType() === "script" &&
                    response.headers()["content-type"] &&
                    response.headers()["content-type"].includes("javascript")) {
                        const js = await response.text();
                        const grepPartResult = grepMagicWords(js);
                        grepResult.push([response.request().url(), grepPartResult]);
                }
            } catch (e) {}
        });

        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        try {
            await page.goto("http://" + site, {waitUntil: "load", timeout: 60000});
            await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 10000); });
        } catch (e) { console.error(e); }

        const [flows, url] = await Promise.race([
            page.evaluate(() => [J$.FLOWS, document.URL]),
            new Promise((_, reject) => { setTimeout(() => { reject(); }, 5000); })
        ]);

        return {url: url, grepResult: grepResult, flows: flows};
    } finally {
        await page.close();
    }

    function grepMagicWords(js) {
        var re = /(?:\'|\")(?:g|s)etItem(?:\'|\")/g, match, result = [];
        while (match = re.exec(js)) {
            result.push(js.substring(match.index - 100, match.index + 100));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

})();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch multiple browsers and run them in parallel. You would have to restructure your app slighltly for that. Create a wrapper for `crawl` which launches it with a new browser instance. I created `crawlNewInstance` which does that for you. You would also need to run `crawlNewInstance()` in parallel.
Checkout this code:

```
const sites = (await fsPromises.readFile(process.argv[2])) // sites list in csv file
    .toString()
    .split("\n")
    .map(line => line.split(",")[1])
    .filter(s => s);

const crawlerProms = sites.map(async (site, index) => {
    try {
        console.log(`[${index}] ${site}`);
        await fsPromises.appendFile("data.txt", JSON.stringify(await crawlNewInstance(site)) + "\n");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

// await all the crawlers!.
await Promise.all(crawlerProms)

async function crawlNewInstance(site) {
    const browser = await pptr.launch({
        args: [
            "--proxy-server=https://127.0.0.1:8000",
            "--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=" + process.env.PROXY_SPKI_FINGERPRINT,
            "--disable-web-security",
        ],
        // headless: false,
    });

    const result = await crawl(browser, site)
    await browser.close()
    return result
}
```

##### optional

The above answers basically the question. But If you want to go further I was in a run and had nothing todo :)

If you have plenty of pages, which you wanted to crawl in parallel and for example limit the amount of parallel requests you could use a `Queue`:

```js
var { EventEmitter} = require('events')

class AsyncQueue extends EventEmitter {
    limit = 2
    enqueued = []
    running = 0

    constructor(limit) {
        super()
        this.limit = limit
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return this.enqueued.length === 0
    }

    // make sure to only pass `async` function to this queue!
    enqueue(fn) {
        // add to queue
        this.enqueued.push(fn)

        // start a job. If max instances are already running it does nothing.
        // otherwise it runs a new job!.
        this.next()
    }

    // if a job is done try starting a new one!.
    done() {
        this.running--
        console.log('job done! remaining:', this.limit - this.running)
        this.next()
    }

    async next() {

        // emit if queue is empty once.
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            this.emit('empty')
            return
        }

        // if no jobs are available OR limit is reached do nothing
        if(this.running >= this.limit) {
            console.log('queueu full.. waiting!')
            return
        }

        this.running++
        console.log('running job!  remaining slots:', this.limit - this.running)

        // first in, first out! so take first element in array.
        const job = this.enqueued.shift()

        try {
            await job()
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Job failed!. ', err)
            this.emit('error', err)
        }

        // job is done!
        // Done() will call the next job if there are any available!.
        this.done()

    }

}
```

The queue could be utilised with this code:

```js
// create queue
const limit = 3
const queue = new AsyncQueue(limit)

// listen for any errors..
queue.on('error', err => {
    console.error('error occured in queue.', err)
})
    
for(let site of sites) {

    // enqueue all crawler jobs.
    // pass an async function which does whatever you want. In this case it crawls
    // a web page!.
    queue.enqueue(async() => {
        await fsPromises.appendFile("data.txt", JSON.stringify(await crawlNewInstance(site)) + "\n");
    })
}


// helper for watiing for the queue!
const waitForQueue = async () => {
    if(queue.isEmpty) return Promise.resolve()

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        queue.once('empty', res)
    })
}

await waitForQueue()

console.log('crawlers done!.')
```

##### Even further with BrowserPool

It would also be possible to reuse your browser instances, so it would not be necessary to start a new browser instance for every crawling process. This can be done using this `Browserpool` helper class

```js
var pptr = require('puppeteer')
async function launchPuppeteer() {
    return await pptr.launch({
        args: [
            "--proxy-server=https://127.0.0.1:8000",
            "--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=" + process.env.PROXY_SPKI_FINGERPRINT,
            "--disable-web-security",
        ],
        // headless: false,
    });
}

// manages browser connections. 
// creates a pool on startup and allows getting references to 
// the browsers! .
class BrowserPool {

    browsers = []

    async get() {
        // return browser if there is one!
        if(this.browsers.length > 0) {
            return this.browsers.splice(0, 1)[0]
        }

        // no browser available anymore.. 
        // launch a new one!
        return await launchPuppeteer()
    }

    // used for putting a browser back in pool!.
    handback(browser) {
        this.browsers.push(browser)
    }

    // shuts down all browsers!.
    async shutDown() {
        for(let browser of this.browsers) {
            await browser.close()
        }
    }

}
```

You can then remove `crawlNewInstance()` and adjust the code to look like this finally:

```js
const sites = (await fsPromises.readFile(process.argv[2])) // sites list in csv file
    .toString()
    .split("\n")
    .map(line => line.split(",")[1])
    .filter(s => s);


// create browserpool
const pool = new BrowserPool()

// create queue
const limit = 3
const queue = new AsyncQueue(3)

// listen to errors:
queue.on('error', err => {
    console.error('error in the queue detected!', err)
})

// enqueue your jobs
for(let site of sites) {

    // enqueue an async function which takes a browser from pool
    queue.enqueue(async () => {
        try {

            // get the browser and crawl a page!.
            const browser = await pool.get()
            const result = await crawl(browser, site)
            await fsPromises.appendFile("data.txt", JSON.stringify(result) + "\n");

            // return the browser back to pool so other crawlers can use it! .
            pool.handback(browser)

        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
        
    })
}

// helper for watiing for the queue!
const waitForQueue = async () => {

    // maybe jobs fail in a few milliseconds so check first if its already empty..
    if(queue.isEmpty) return Promise.resolve()
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        queue.once('empty', res)
    })
}
// wait for the queue to finish :)
await waitForQueue()

// in the very end, shut down all browser:
await pool.shutDown()

console.log('done!.')
```

Have fun and feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your brief answer. Sorry for my late response because I was out of work. I will try this and inform you if there's any problem. Thank you again